# Swagger Schema error should NOT have additional properties

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am trying to create swagger json and trying to check it's validity in 
http://editor.swagger.io

Upon validating the json, the above mentioned editor gives the following error:

```
Schema error should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: components
Jump to line 0
```

If for some reason I can't define an element named components at root level where i am going to have some sort of json schema, what is the right way to do a $ref on the schema for requestBody for an API operation as I intend to do as seen in my example below. Also, do you see anything wrong with my swagger json ?

My swagger json for swagger2.0 look like this.

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "title": "My swagger API",
        "contact": {
            "name": "myName",
            "email": "abc@gmail.com"
        }
    },
    "host": "localhost:1234",
    "basePath": "/",
    "tags": [{
        "name": "someTagName",
        "description": "this is a try"
    }],
    "components":{"schemas": {"myEndPoint": ""}},
    "paths": {
        "/myEndPoint": {
            "post": {
                "tags": ["some-tag"],
                "summary": "myEndPoint endpoint will give you something",
                "description": "some description will go here",
                "operationId": "getMyEndPoint",
                "consumes": ["application/json"],
                "produces": ["application/json"],
                "parameters": [{
                    "in": "body",
                    "name": "somePayload",
                    "description": "somePayload is what this is",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "$ref": "#components/schemas/myEndPoint"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "in": "header",
                    "name": "Authorization",
                    "description": "auth token goes here",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Success",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "400": {
                        "description": "Bad Request"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are mixing up OpenAPI 3.0 and 2.0 syntax. The `components` keyword is used in OpenAPI 3.0. In OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, reusable schemas live under `definitions`:

```
"definitions": {
  "myEndPoint": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Make sure to also change the `$ref` to

```
"$ref": "#/definitions/myEndPoint"
```